# Why am I getting different results using different methods of determining duplicate records in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I am running the following queries in MS SQL Server 2014, and I am getting more duplicates using the CTE technique rather than the first.

(Perhaps unnecessary background: this is a large table consisting of patient related data looking at admissions to the hospital within 30 days after a procedure. So the criteria for duplicate rows includes both the admission identifier "admitPK" and the procedure identifier "procedurePK")

**First method:**

```
SELECT [admitPK]
FROM db.table
GROUP BY [admitPK], [procedurePK]
HAVING COUNT(*) >1
```

**CTE Method:**

```
WITH dupes as (
    SELECT *
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
         PARTITION BY [admitPK], [procedurePK]
         ORDER BY ([admitPK])) as RN
    FROM db.table)
SELECT *
FROM dupes
WHERE RN > 1
```

The CTE method returns about 1.8% more duplicate rows than the first. On further analysis, the CTE method is correct. 
I am sure this is something simple I am missing. Just trying to learn **why the difference** for my future choices. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Do you get a lot of rows where RN > 2?

Comment: If you change `WHERE RN > 1` to `WHERE RN = 2`, does it even out?

Comment: I could answer this, as I'm sure could the previous two commenters, but with just a little analysis, you should be able to figure this out.   What difference do you see between the results of the first query and the second?   Also, think about what a GROUP BY clause does.

Comment: I'll burst the bubble. The `GROUP BY` query will produce *1* row for each group. The `WHERE RN > 1` query will produce the first duplicate as a row where RN = 2, the second duplicate (triplicate?) row as a row where RN = 3, and so on. If you have exactly 2 duplicates when there are duplicates, the two queries should produce the same number of rows. If some groups have more than 2 rows matching, they will differ.

Comment: You are all correct. If I change to WHERE RN = 2, I do get the same number of rows. And now I understand! Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

This was answered in the comments section, and seems obvious now. Best explained by Lasse Karlsen. The GROUP BY query produces one row for each group, if there are 2, 3 or more duplicates. So even those rows that have multiple duplicates still only produce one row in this query.
The WHERE RN > 1 query lists all the duplicate rows (except of course the first list in the partition). So for me, it seems the CTE method is the most accurate to delete duplicate rows.

Comment: Another way to summarize is that the CTE method will return all the duplicate rows, while the GROUP BY will return all the original rows that have at least one duplicate.